# Azure function local debugging problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, debugging, azure-functions

Whenever I'm creating a function app locally (with vscode) the project gets created,

When I debug locally the `az` function, the debugger runs successfully,

When I add any library in the `requirements.txt` file, and try to debug, the library gets installed, but I'm getting a huge error as the following:

Does it make sense? Is there any explanation that explains why I'm at the virtual `env` of the `az` function, and I'm getting this error? I'm seeing the libraries at the debugger level with:

```
import sys
import os

def get_virtual_env_path():
if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix') or (hasattr(sys, 'base_prefix') and sys.base_prefix != sys.prefix):
\# Virtual environment is likely active
return sys.prefix
elif 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
\# Check if VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable is set
return os.environ\['VIRTUAL_ENV'\]
else:
return None

# Example usage

virtual_env_path = get_virtual_env_path()

if virtual_env_path:
print(f"The path to the active virtual environment is: {virtual_env_path}")
else:
print("No virtual environment is currently active.")
```

It's the case for all my az functions ones were correctly behaving,

`Worker failed to load function: 'HttpTrigger1' with functionId: '62b41d74-8a9b-46b9-a6db-9ccabee3c906'. [2024-02-01T16:26:42.644Z] Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 387, in _handle__function_load_request     func = loader.load_function(   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 48, in call     raise extend_exception_message(e, message)   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 44, in call     return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 194, in load_function     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\project_test\test\HttpTrigger1\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>     import pandas as pd`
.

Edit **Solution** : I have found the root cause,

After days of investigations i figured out that when i launch a function in the debugger (any func host start) related process, azurefunction launches some biuil-in enviromenet dependencies + my .env file so the problem was that there were a dependency conflict on the azure func start,

1. I deleted the cache for vscode, Removed vscode
2. **Important** : Deleted cache + fully delete azure function core tools as well as all the related vscode extension, which don't gets deleted during uninstall
3. Deleted python
4. Cleaned my laptop for empty / corrupted folders
5. Re-install all

And we are good.

Thanks everyone for your answer, much apperciated.

Comment: Please share your Http trigger `__init__.py` Code?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense? is there any explanation that explains why i'm at the virtual env of the az function, and i'm getting this error ?

When an Azure Function is created in VS Code, a default virtual environment is generated in the project folder with the name `.venv`. All installed modules are available inside this virtual environment, and your local function runs within it, allowing for dynamic module requirements.

If the virtual environment is not created you can create manually and activate it to execute or debug the azure function locally, the steps are:

- Create a virtual environment using this command `python -m venv .venv`
- Activate the virtual environment using ( in Windows) `.venv\Scripts\activate`

  - (in Linux or macOS) source `.venv/bin/activate`,  After activating it looks like this
    [image]
- Install dependencies using `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- Run the function locally using `func start` or `func host start`

Also when you open you `requirements.txt` file at the right bottom corner you will see option to `create environment`

[image]

please mention the required modules in `requirements.txt` file

```py
azure-functions
pandas
# for specific version requirement mention like this:
# pandas==2.2.0
```

Here I have created a simple Http trigger which is printing `pandas` version used in the code.

**#My Directory :**

```
├── flask
│   ├── .venv
│   ├── HttpTrigger1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── function.json
│   ├── .funcignore
│   ├── host.json
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── local.settings.json
```

[image]

**`HttpTrigger1/__init__.py`:**

```py
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # Ensure pandas is imported successfully
        print(f"Pnadas version : {pd.__version__}")

        # Your function logic here
        result = {"message": "Hello from Azure Functions!"}

        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=json.dumps(result),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"Error: {str(e)}"
        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=json.dumps({"error": error_message}),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=500
        )
```

**`HttpTrigger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["get",
          "post"
      ]
  },
  {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
  }
  ]
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-05T10:38:36.802Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-05T10:38:40.779Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=6627862a-1689-4fe7-ac49-cd4640840586)
[2024-02-05T10:38:40.858Z] Pnadas version : 2.2.0
[2024-02-05T10:38:40.937Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=6627862a-1689-4fe7-ac49-cd4640840586, Duration=190ms)
```

[image]

```json
{
    "message": "Hello from Azure Functions!"
}
```

[image]